# Automatically log me into windows

Tags: teamcity

I'm using TeamCity to management running our automation test suite. The build steps are standard and include:

- Command Line - get latest code
- Command Line - build project
- MSTest - run tests

But as these tests run on an external test machine/agent, and I need to be logged into the machine for the tests to run successfully (testing a WPF App):

I want to add build steps to automatically log me into windows as a pre step and log me out again after the test suite is completed.

Example:

- (PRE - LOG ME INTO WINDOWS)
- Command Line - get latest code
- Command Line - build project
- MSTest - run tests
- (POST - LOG ME OUT)

Any ideas on how I can utilise one of the build steps (CMD, Powershell etc) to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware it is not possible to automatically log on to a Windows machine, access the desktop and then log off because of the way Windows handles the [separation](http://www.brianbondy.com/blog/id/100/) between the desktop session and the log on session.

You could solve your problem by creating a VM that is permanently logged on (don't forget to turn off the lock screen and the screen saver) which you can then use for your test work. I'm suggesting using a VM for this because the machine will need to be permanently logged on, with the lock screen and screen saver disabled, again because of the way Windows deals with the different [sessions](http://www.brianbondy.com/blog/id/100/) (desktop session vs screen saver session vs lock screen session). Having a physical machine with an unlocked desktop most likely means that people will use it for other purposes which will interfere with your testing work. Using a VM means that people are less likely to access the machine and you could put it on a section of the network where people can't remote connect to it.

If you really want either automatic log-on and log-off or automatic resetting of the test environment to a known state then you will have to do some work to provide automatic VM start-up and shut-down. The way we resolved this problem at our company was to write a [service](https://github.com/pvandervelde/Sherlock) that is capable of starting / stopping the VMs when they are needed for a test and of controlling the test execution. 
This way we have a set of test machines on which we have an interactive log on while keeping the machine relatively 'secure' (all VM's run on a server to which people have very limited access) and we can return the machine back to a known state after the tests by applying an existing snapshot.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response Petrik. Unfortunately due to company bureaucracy I cannot use VM's. On my physical test agent I have disabled screen lock and screen saver. This does allow me to run the test suite uninterrupted over night, but I would like the security of control over windows login/out.

Comment: One option would be to use the [Wake-on-Lan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) approach to start the machine. You can then run [AutoLogOn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905.aspx) to automatically log on. At the end of the test you could run a script that turns the PC off. That should give you the security you want. [Sherlock](https://github.com/pvandervelde/Sherlock) has code for Wake-on-LAN but I've never tested that bit of the code because I don't have physical test machines available. Feel free to try it if you think it is beneficial for your situation.